# What's the status of encfs?

Tags: security, encryption, encfs

Is the [encfs](http://www.arg0.net/encfs) project no longer maintained? It seems the last update 1.7.4 was released on November 18 2010. In a security [audit](https://defuse.ca/audits/encfs.htm) several weaknesses have been identified, but no updates have since been issued. Should encfs still be used? if not, why is it in the standard repositories of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does look as if `encfs` is no longer maintained. It is in Ubuntu 14.04 because it still is in Debian `wheezy`. It has been removed from [Debian `jessie`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=encfs&searchon=names&suite=testing&section=all), so should be gone from future versions of Ubuntu. Like the OP in this Debian [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=736066), I do not have the competence to judge this, but I recommend that you do not use it unless you *have* to, given the removal from `jessie`.

Comment: Thanks, knowing that it will be removed from Ubuntu in the future seems like a very good reason not to start using it now.

Answer (score 6):

The project lives, and is working on a 2.0 revision:

https://github.com/vgough/encfs

"EncFS has been dormant for a while. I've started cleaning up in order to try and provide a better base for a version 2, but whether EncFS flowers again depends upon community interest. In order to make it easier for anyone to contribute, it is moving a new home on Github. So if you're interested in EncFS, please dive in!"﻿

Answer (score 1):

Edit: See the comment by [jpnp](https://askubuntu.com/users/340917/jpnp) below which suggests [gocryptfs](https://github.com/rfjakob/gocryptfs)

**As [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813290/encfs-insecure-what-to-use-now) answer states encfs is indeed not safe nor maintained any longer.**

So to completely answer your question there are several alternatives to encrypt files and folders, listed from simple to extensive encryption possibilities:

- [Gnu Privacy Guard (GPG)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuPrivacyGuardHowto)
- [Hidden encrypted volumes using TrueCrypt (GUI)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TrueCrypt)
- [eCryptfs](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ecryptfs.html.en)

And there are really many more.

Also look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/714069/whats-currently-the-most-secure-encryption-software) for a similar answer, it might help you.

Comment: For others finding this old question: [gocryptfs](https://github.com/rfjakob/gocryptfs) is the most direct replacement for encfs.  Written by a former encfs contributor, it uses the same model of file based encryption via FUSE, and is a near drop-in replacement, but with more modern encryption.  It has also survived an [audit](https://defuse.ca/audits/gocryptfs.htm) without serious issues.