# Access cryptkeeper files in 20.14?

Tags: 20.04, encryption, gui, encfs, cryptkeeper

I just updated to 20.04. I have some files encrypted with cryptkeeper on another drive. I see its not supported anymore. How can I access the files. Are there any GUI programs I can use?

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047704/cryptkeeper-removed-from-ubuntu-18-04) help?

Comment: Yes it helped. Saw thru this message when trying earlier, but must have overseen something... Thank you!