# how to protect a folder using password in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: password, encryption, encfs, cryptkeeper

I have tried installing both cryptkeeper and gnome-encfs-manager but it was showing unable to locate the packages. Can anyone please help me in installing any one of them or suggest a new one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cryptkeeper removed from Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047704/cryptkeeper-removed-from-ubuntu-18-04) (see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1050859/480481)

Comment: Cryptkeeper (EncFS) is an obsolete and discredited technology, you should look for [better alternatives](https://askubuntu.com/q/813290/480481).

Answer (score 0):

I took the easy way to encrypt my files.  I installed the snap 7zip and made an archive of my files and encrypted them with a strong password at the time of zip creation.

Works for what I need it for just a bunch of files I need to access one at a time because I can just double click the one I want from within the archive.